# Does the C# compiler knows if the same calculation is done in two places?

Tags: c#

```
 if ( Math.Pow(functionofY, 3.0) > 0.008856 )
      {
        functionofY = Math.Pow(functionofY, 3);
      }
```

if I have this function, will the compiler calculate the power just once? or does it go through your code and find duplicate calculations? i feel like the compiler is a magic black box sometimes.

Comment: You're calling them differently.

Comment: If you really want to find out, look at the IL the compiler generates. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The compiler has no way of knowing if a given function returns the same output when given the same input.

Comment: The compiler also has no way of knowing if a given function returns the same output when given *different* input. :)

Comment: Agree with @Brian Rasmussed, the compiler would need to know if `Math.Pow` is deterministic. It seems likely that it does not. (and also that `3` in convertible to `3.0` which is more likely)

Comment: The compiler has no way of knowing what a function does regardless of input.

Comment: I thought all methods are deterministic

Comment: That'd make a method that returns random numbers difficult.

Comment: @WeylandYutani Simplest example against that is `DateTime.Now` which is (even worse) a property. But no, all functions can have side effects; they could count up a static number, and return 4 whenever that counter is divisible by 42.

Comment: The .Net random number generator is deterministic

Comment: @WeylandYutani what if access some volatile state, like the time or a `static` variable inside the class.

Comment: That's really irrelevant, calls to `Random.Next()` don't always return the same thing.

Comment: still deterministic, the same state when called will produce the same output

Comment: calls to Random.Next() do return the same thing if the seed is the same

Comment: @WeylandYutani What about multi-threading and concurrency?

Comment: @WeylandYutani Deterministic when considering every kind of input that exists, yes. But the functions themselves, which take a fixed amount of input (e.g. nothing), are still non-deterministic because they won’t produce the same result with the same parameters.

Comment: @WeylandYutani "Deterministic" in this context means that function returns the same value given the same input, not that you can predict output.

Comment: @WeylandYutani what if they take some data from the network, from say, a weather station?

Comment: okay clearly I don't understand what the word deterministic means, so sorry

Comment: "i feel like the compiler is a magic black box sometimes." - everything looks like a black box before you understand it :) For what it's worth some languages _are_ able to optimize this call (if the arguments are exactly the same) - just not languages with uncontrolled side effects like C#.

Comment: even the weather is deterministic. I guess here deterministic is used in a different sense.

Comment: @Mysticial The C# compiler makes very few guarantees when it comes to multithreaded programming.  Virtually all of its guarantees, are based on what can be observed from a single thread.

Comment: @WeylandYutani I don't want to argue whether the weather is deterministic. So, *you* name a non-deterministic process. Call it X. What if they take some data from the network, from say, something that measures X?

Comment: This is getting very off-topic. I would suggest to either move to chat, or create a “What is a deterministic function” question instead…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it will execute the function call twice. The compiler has no way of knowing what side effects the function call may have, or whether it will return the same value with the same inputs.

If you want it to only be called once, store the result of the first call in a local variable, and then use that instead.

```
tempVal = Math.Pow(functionofY, 3);
if (tempVal > 0.008856)
{
  functionofY = tempVal;
}
```

Comment: It also doesn't know what side effect other functions may have performed that would alter the state of the parameters to the function or any internal state that it might rely on that could affect its output.

Comment: Note this is not exactly the same call OP is having since the second argument is on a different type on both invocations.

Comment: +1. To be very precise - compiler has a way of knowing some particular functions have no side effect (and JIT'er too), but compiler *must not* try to use that knowledge as C# does not have concept of [pure functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). Picking language from other set of languages - [functional languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Functional_languages) - would allow such optimization on compiler level.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum There is only one overload to `Pow`.  `3` is actually converted to a double implicitly before being passed to `Pow`.  So the arguments, in this specific case, *are* the same.

Comment: so if it were not a function call, and merely a variable, then the compiler will be able to optimize it out right?

Comment: @James: Optimize *what* out? The variable or function call? No, because it doesn't know the value of the function result until it's executed, and that doesn't happen until the code executes.

Comment: I guess the compiler could work out that there are no side-effects, and optimise it. I'm sure it won't, but I think it could. I don't think that the language spec. would stop the compiler doing that.

Comment: oh i just meant that if i have 
if (x -y > 10)
{
   z = x-y;
}, does the compiler calculate x  - y twice?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of optimizations is probably up to the JITter, which might indeed optimize this out. But actually it doesn't, as the following disassembly shows (taken with OllyDbg from a Release-mode compiled and optimization-enabled console application):

```
00340070    55              PUSH EBP
00340071    8BEC            MOV EBP,ESP

System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break( );
00340073    E8 007D8A5D     CALL 5DBE7D78

double functionofY = 1;
00340078    DD05 E0003400   FLD QWORD PTR DS:[3400E0]                ; FLOAT 1.000000000000000
0034007E    83EC 08         SUB ESP,8
00340081    DD1C24          FSTP QWORD PTR SS:[ESP]

if ( Math.Pow( functionofY, 3.0 ) > 0.008856 )
00340084    DD05 E8003400   FLD QWORD PTR DS:[3400E8]                ; FLOAT 3.000000000000000
0034008A    83EC 08         SUB ESP,8
0034008D    DD1C24          FSTP QWORD PTR SS:[ESP]
00340090    E8 6921C05F     CALL 5FF421FE
00340095    DD05 F0003400   FLD QWORD PTR DS:[3400F0]                ; FLOAT 0.008855999999999999
0034009B    DFF1            FCOMIP ST,ST(1)
0034009D    DDD8            FSTP ST
0034009F    7A 21           JPE SHORT 003400C2
003400A1    73 1F           JNB SHORT 003400C2

functionofY = Math.Pow( functionofY, 3 );
003400A3    DD05 F8003400   FLD QWORD PTR DS:[3400F8]                ; FLOAT 1.000000000000000
003400A9    83EC 08         SUB ESP,8
003400AC    DD1C24          FSTP QWORD PTR SS:[ESP]
003400AF    DD05 00013400   FLD QWORD PTR DS:[340100]                ; FLOAT 3.000000000000000
003400B5    83EC 08         SUB ESP,8
003400B8    DD1C24          FSTP QWORD PTR SS:[ESP]
003400BB    E8 3E21C05F     CALL 5FF421FE
003400C0    DDD8            FSTP ST

Console.WriteLine( "LOL" );
003400C2    E8 7DF9295D     CALL 5D5DFA44
003400C7    8BC8            MOV ECX,EAX
003400C9    8B15 30203603   MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[3362030]
003400CF    8B01            MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[ECX]
003400D1    8B40 3C         MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+3C]
003400D4    FF50 10         CALL DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+10]
003400D7    5D              POP EBP
003400D8    C3              RETN
```